# mysql: Addition on Sum() of 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sum, union

There are two separate tables with multiple entries (rows) that we need to add (sum) together to form one value.

The query below gives me 2 distinct values on the return, I'm looking to just add the 2 together to form 1 value. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
select sum(t1.netAmount) 
      from tbl_one t1 where userid = 4033 and date > '2014-09-01'
    Union All
    select sum(t2.netAmount) 
      from tbl_two t2 where userid = 4033 and date > '2014-09-01'
```

Table structures below

```
tbl_one
userid   |   netAmount   |   date
---------------------------------
4033     |   20          | 2014-09-02 12:00:00
4033     |   -20         | 2014-09-02 12:01:00
4033     |   40          | 2014-09-02 12:02:00


tbl_two
userid   |   netAmount   |   date
---------------------------------
4033     |   05          | 2014-09-03 12:00:00
4033     |   -100        | 2014-09-03 12:01:00
4033     |   12          | 2014-09-03 12:02:00
```

Getting the true sum across both tables for 4033 would yield -43 (40 + -83)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your database looks like so this is untested, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT SUM(netAmount) FROM (
  SELECT netAmount FROM tbl_one WHERE userid = 4033 AND `date` > "2014-09-01"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT netAmount FROM tbl_two WHERE userid = 4033 AND `date` > "2014-09-01"
) x
```

Comment: That yields #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. I'll add some more details on the table structure in the original question.

Comment: Did you remember that x at the end?

Comment: SELECT sum(netAmount) FROM (
  SELECT sum(netAmount) as netAmount FROM tbl_one WHERE userid = 4033 AND `date` > "2014-09-01"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sum(netAmount) as netAmount FROM tbl_two WHERE userid = 4033 AND `date` > "2014-09-01"
) x